# Making ClickOnce Updates Mandatory?

Tags: c#, clickonce

Currently in an application I'm building I have it check for updates, and it gives the user the option to install or not to install the updates. 
I want it to just automatically install the updates no matter what. 
How can I make this change?

Comment: See the answer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184141/clickonce-automatically-making-all-builds-required

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Automatic Updates

[Choosing a ClickOnce Update Strategy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e.aspx) (**Making Updates Required**)

One options is to set up automatic updates to your software and mark them as required by setting the minimum required version in your deployment manifest.  You can set this in the properties dialog in Visual Studio, or through configuration with the following tag: `<deployment install="true" minimumRequiredVersion="1.0.0.0">`.  The minimum required version checks the version of your assembly, and if it is not at least what you specify here it will force an update.

## Programmatic Updates

[How to: Add On-Demand Programmatic Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc558901.aspx)

Another option that will allow you more control of when and how often the update occurs is to do the updates programmatically.  You can use the ClickOnce API to check for any updates on the deployment server and install them once your application has been run.  You can have far more control over what updates should be installed, how they are installed, and how you notify the user of the updates.  If your application is generally a long running instance, you could also set up timers to run in the background every so often to do the updates as well.

Here is an example implementation that polls on an interval: [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc558902.aspx).

You can also combine the above two update methods.

Comment: I believe setting the minimum required version will give the user the option to upgrade, or close the app.

Comment: Is there an way to automatically set the minimum required version to the most current version, or do you have to manually change this value each time you publish a new version?

Comment: I've appended the answer with another option for you to look at.  You could create build tasks that automatically update the minimum required version within the ClickOnce deployment manifest for you as part of your build / deployment process as well.

Comment: Nate -- it does not give the user any chance to say yes or no, it just installs the update.

Comment: Soo -- no, but that is a feature request I have turned in to the ClickOnce product team.

Comment: Great answer but unfortunately the links are dead

Comment: @Derek: The original Example is no longer online, but it is in the [Internet Archive's Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc558902.aspx).

There's also this other example on MSDN: [How to: Check for Application Updates Programmatically Using the ClickOnce Deployment API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

Simply you can achieve by adding below `<target>` tag in your project's `.csproj` file.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    // Other Tags ...

    <Target Name="AutoSetMinimumRequiredVersion" BeforeTargets="GenerateDeploymentManifest">
        <FormatVersion Version="$(ApplicationVersion)" Revision="$(ApplicationRevision)">
            <Output PropertyName="MinimumRequiredVersion" TaskParameter="OutputVersion" />
        </FormatVersion>
        <FormatVersion Version="$(ApplicationVersion)" Revision="$(ApplicationRevision)">
            <Output PropertyName="_DeploymentBuiltMinimumRequiredVersion" TaskParameter="OutputVersion" />
        </FormatVersion>
    </Target>

    // Other Tags ...

</Project>
```

It will automatically make your each publish/update mandatory without doing any extra stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The "Auto Update Project's Minimum Required ClickOnce Version" project has a nuget package that updates the ClickOnce settings for you.

https://aupmrcov.codeplex.com/ [ archived ]

GitHub:

https://github.com/deadlydog/AutoUpdateProjectsMinimumRequiredClickOnceVersion

Nuget:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoUpdateProjectsMinimumRequiredClickOnceVersion

Comment: This deserves more love.. and a GITHub page

Answer (score 0):

If you specify minimum required version same as the current publish version, your application will update as soon as clients open it.

1-Just right-click on the project name 
2-Select Properties
3-Click Publish (Note publish version)
4-Click on Update button 
5-Select "Specify minimum required version for this application"
and 
Finally, make version number same as the "Publish Version".