# Automatic update from clickonce application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

I want an C# application which can be installed on someones computer and updates it self if a newer version is available. (The conection is only for this application is within one company)

If I install the application, change something in the code, publish it again it won't check if there is an new application available.

This are my settings: [Assembly Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54DLP.png)  | [Publish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohThd.png)  | [Publish - Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m72fJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to publish to an intranet website within the company. If they have multiple servers (e.g. load-balanced or standby), publish to one IIS site and copy/paste to the other servers - don't publish to each server individually as the application versions won't match. By default, IIS will stop the install setup EXE running so remove the EXE handler from the site's handlers - simply delete it.

Using this scenario, when a user runs the application it will check the website for a newer version (if they have access) and run with the old version if not, or install your newer version, if available.

You'll also find the published folders contain all previous versions - you might want to remove all previous versions before copying around the IIS sites

Comment: What is the difference between publish my application to a server-share and publish my application to the webserver? This doesn't solve my problem

Comment: The user updates the application by visiting the website but you publish to the folder over the network

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for updating clickOnce automatically when any new version is available in server? If yes, setting `Minmum required Version` to your latest version might help. Below link may help you

[Making ClickOnce Updates Mandatory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103534/making-clickonce-updates-mandatory?rq=1)

Comment: Check my latest picture, there is the screenshot with that box checked

Comment: in case you want update to kick in automatically you need to keep `Minimum Required Version` same as you release version. Here i can see release version is 1.0.1.23 and minimum required version is less than that, i.e 1.0.1.22.