# How can I force an oneclick application to restart and update?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, auto-update, oneclick

I have a OneClick WPF application deployed but unfortunately I am having trouble updating the application.Previously, I was using Application.Deployemnt's update() function, but since Application.Deployment is no longer available, how do I go about forcing the application to restart to trigger the update?

So far I tried `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();` and
`string currentPath = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName; Process.Start(currentPath);`

but this is just restarting the application, not triggering the update to the new published version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103534/making-clickonce-updates-mandatory